# I keep getting <Response [200]> from requests, how do I get the content?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I keep getting `<Response [200]>` from requests. I'm expecting to get something like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "assembly",
    "url": "https://run.glot.io/languages/assembly"
  },
  {
    "name": "bash",
    "url": "https://run.glot.io/languages/bash"
  },
  {
    "name": "c",
    "url": "https://run.glot.io/languages/c"
  },
  {
    "name": "clojure",
    "url": "https://run.glot.io/languages/clojure"
  }
]
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://run.glot.io/languages', verify=False)
print(response)
```

How can I get the actual content?

Comment: `response` is an object, try printing `response.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to process the response as JSON. Try:

```
json = response.json()
print(json)
```

`200` is the HTTP Status Code for the response, indicating OK. You'll want to access the content to actually parse the response. See: https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Answer (score 1):

Because response is an object, you have to print out `response.content`.